# Sequelize "SELECT * from tablename" query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Why the query below executes `SELECT id, email, name FROM users AS users WHERE users.email = 'admin@admin.com';` rather than `SELECT * from users WHERE email = admin@admin.com` ?

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#where

Documentation states that it'll run a SELECT * query when I do findAll(), but it does something different in my example. What's missing here?

Here's my users model.

```
var user = sequelize.define('users', {
        id : {
            type : Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey : true,
            autoIncrement : true
        },
        email : {
            type : Sequelize.STRING
        },
        name : {
            type : Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'users',
        freezeTableName: true
    });
```

And this is my query. It seems that it only selects defined columns, but I don't want this.

```
var email = "admin@admin.com";
user.findAll({where: {email: email}}).then(function (user) {
    res.send(user);

}).error(function (err) {
    console.log("Error:" + err);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior of sequelize selecting only the columns which you have defined.  If you want to select all of the columns using sequelize you must define them in your model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use like `select * from tablename`, then just use:

```
var email = "admin@admin.com";
user.findAll().then(function (user) {
    res.send(user);

}).error(function (err) {
    console.log("Error:" + err);
});
```